# loss of data indexdb when browser version updates

Tags: indexeddb, offlineapps

What happens when I store data in the IndexDB and browser is updated, Does IndexDB keep data or clear storage?

Tks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes indexdb`s data automatically remove, Does anyone know how we can prevent this? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, data is retained across browser updates. Unless of course the browser has a bug.